# xsl - format-number from one to two digits 1 => 01

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

is there in XSLT some function or somethg to alow format digits
like eg 1 will become 01

so if I have

```
<a>10</a>
<b>5</b>
```

they will apear as

```
A10

and

B05
```

Comment: Where are the A" and "B" characters supposed to come from?

Answer (score 3):

**Function [Formating numbers](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number):**

```
<xsl:template match="root/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 1.0 uppercase of nodenames:**

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:value-of select="translate(name(), $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
```

**Combined:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(name(), $smallcase, $uppercase), format-number(.,'00'))" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
format-number(5, '00')
```

returns "05".

Similarly,

```
format-number(10, '00')
```

returns "10".